# How to print PHP equation to analyze it?

Tags: php

I've got a simple script with a lot of formulas like so:

```
$formula = 12 *( $C + ($D * $A) + $H ) + $B * ((($F+$J)*$M/$L)+(($G+$K)*$N/$L)+$E);
```

Is there any easy way to output the values to debug the equation? Like:

```
12 * ( 15 (44 * 11) + 33) + 3 * [...]
```

Or I have to to do it the usual way:

```
echo "12" . '* ('. $C .' + ' [...]
```

I've got lot of these formulas, so I'm looking for some shortcut to debug them.

Comment: This is why we don't write long formulas like this.

Comment: There are no shortcuts with math...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to surround your formula with double quotes like so:

```
$formula = "12 *( $C + ($D * $A) + $H ) + $B * ((($F+$J)*$M/$L)+(($G+$K)*$N/$L)+$E)";
```

That will allow you to echo $formula and all of the variables should be converted to their actual values.

As far as a way to do that without copy/paste or inserting the quotes, no.  PHP is going to evaluate all the stuff on the right side of the = so that $formula ends up (without the quotes) with just the final result. If you want the result and the "debug" output you could do this:

```
$formula = 12 *( $C + ($D * $A) + $H ) + $B * ((($F+$J)*$M/$L)+(($G+$K)*$N/$L)+$E);
$formulaDebug = "12 *( $C + ($D * $A) + $H ) + $B * ((($F+$J)*$M/$L)+(($G+$K)*$N/$L)+$E)";

echo $formulaDebug . " = " . $formula . PHP_EOL;
```

Then you'll get both the answer and the debug output.

Comment: Owww. Man You rock, I feel so stupid right now... If that is not obvious than I dont know what is...

Comment: Make sure you use double quotes. Single quotes will display the formula without the variable substitution happening.

Answer (score 3):

If you wrap the equation in quotes, it will resolve the variables but not do the math, like so:

```
 $formula = "12 *( $C + ($D * $A) + $H ) + $B * ((($F+$J)*$M/$L)+(($G+$K)*$N/$L)+$E)";
```

If you want to actually solve the equation using the string, you can use `eval()`, like so:

```
$formula = "12 *( $C + ($D * $A) + $H ) + $B * ((($F+$J)*$M/$L)+(($G+$K)*$N/$L)+$E)";

echo $formula; \\ Equation with vars filled in.

eval( "echo $formula;");  \\ Solved equation
```

Be aware that eval is pretty powerful and that it will throw an error if the variables are not defined, as the equation won't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

So when you get the data from math, build a string then use eval to do the math !

```
<?php
$Test = '7 * 9';
echo 'Eqau: '.$Test.'<br />';  // Eqau: 7 * 9
eval( "\$Test2 = $Test;" );
echo 'Res: '.$Test2;            // Res: 63
?>
```

Comment: This looks very neat and clear. Just make sure math is all that gets `eval()`:ed

Comment: @micke Yeah, eval is dangerous when open to something not good but you can protect it without problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you should be able to turn the entire calc into a string and then the variables will output their values:
`echo "foo is $foo"; // foo is foobar`

Not sure if this is exactly what you were looking for.